# How to run a script using "dart pub global run" command?

Tags: dart, command-line

The directory of my package `foo`:

[image]

The pubspec.yaml file has:

```
name: foo

executables:
  foo: bar
```

The package `foo` is activated using `dart pub global activate ...` and if I add the directory to `PATH` environment, the following command works:

```
foo bar
```

but if I remove it, and try to run the `dart pub global run` command, it doesn't work.

```
me@mac foo % dart pub global run foo bar
Could not find bin/foo.dart.
```

So, how can I run a script without adding it to the `PATH` using `dart pub global run` as suggested [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global).

> You can directly run a script from an activated package from the command line. If you are unable to run the script directly, you can also use dart pub global run.

**Note**: `dart pub global run foo:bar` works but that doesn't have to do with the executables  defined in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Please show the full `activate` command line

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara `dart pub global activate --source path <path_of_foo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying:

```
executables:
  foo: bar
```

Means that when the package is activated, the command `foo` will map to the file `bar.dart`. There is no need to specify `bar` when invoking it.

For example, I have this package:

```
name: dictionary
...
executables:
    scrabble:
```

It defines an executable `scrabble` that invokes `scrabble.dart`. I activate it like this:

```
dart pub global activate --source path dictionary
```

This reports:

```
...
Installed executable scrabble.
Activated dictionary 1.0.0 at path "[...]\Dart\dictionary".
```

I can invoke the `scrabble` command which invokes `scrabble.dart`. I can also invoke it like this:

```
dart pub global run dictionary:scrabble
```

If my `pubspec` has:

```
executables:
    dictionary: scrabble
```

Then the command `dictionary` invokes the file `scrabble.dart`.

(Do not forget to include the `pub` cache on your `PATH`. For me on Windows this is `C:\Users\pohara\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin`.

**Addition:** continuing with the `dictionary: scrabble` example, when I activate dictionary` I get:

```
...
Installed executable dictionary.
Activated dictionary 1.0.0 at path "[...]\Dart\dictionary".
```

And my `pub` cache on Windows has this file to run the `dictionary` command:

```
> cat C:\Users\pohara\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin\dictionary.bat
@echo off
rem This file was created by pub v2.12.2.
rem Package: dictionary
rem Version: 1.0.0
rem Executable: dictionary
rem Script: scrabble
pub global run dictionary:scrabble %*
```

So the command `dictionary` explicitly runs the `scrabble` file in the `dictionary` package.

Both these commands fail:

```
> dart pub global run dictionary scrabble
Could not find bin\dictionary.dart.

> dart pub global run dictionary
Could not find bin\dictionary.dart.
```

And of course this one succeeds:

```
> dart pub global run dictionary:scrabble
```

This is all consistent with the documentation https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#executables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know how this answers my question. Let me put it the other way. If you haven't added your `pub-cache` to the Path, and you run, (from the docs link itself) `webdev serve` you get an error "zsh: command not found:webdev" but you can directly run the same command using `dart pub global run webdev serve` but why can't I do the same thing for my `foo` package, that's the question.

Comment: `webdev server` is running the package `webdev` with the parameter `serve`. In your example, the package `foo` provides the executable `foo` which invokes the file `bar.dart`. When you run `dart pub global run foo bar`, the term `bar` is just an additional parameter to the `foo` executable.

Comment: Please also see the **Addition** I made to the answer

Comment: Thanks, it is bit clearer now. So, if I got you right, when I do `webdev server` I'm actually running [this file](https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/blob/master/webdev/bin/webdev.dart) and passing `server` as an argument.

Comment: One correction, `server` is actually a sub-command and not a parameter/argument.

Comment: OK, but as far as 'dart pub global run` is concerned it is just an argument to the dart executable.

Comment: Is there any way to know about whether something is a sub-command or parameter/argument just by looking at the command?

Comment: Well behaved executables have help text that tells you what commands/arguments they expect. I use `https://pub.dev/packages/args` to help with this.